# Getting string from site via c #

Tags: javascript, c#

Recently I needed to transfer data from the site (more precisely, the browser extension) to my C# application.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to do it!

I can send data from JS:

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo.url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "http:/localhost:9812/", true);
    http.send(changeInfo.url);
}
});
```

But i dont know, how get this data in C#.
Can you show me how to send data via javascript and receive it via C#?

Comment: Does your application listen to a port?

Comment: I'm guessing its asp net mvc can you show us your c# controller?

Comment: Is your URL in the POST request correct, it seems to be missing a "/" ... "http: // localhost:9812/"